# SP Website not working / Creating new UAT

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

### Background

Need to create a new UAT. Decided to use the Current Live environment.
Created Copy of DC, SP & SQL Servers, Put them in their own little Virtual Bubble.
Everything works.

### Work already done

I've gone through the process of renaming the SharePoint Server (SP first with Powershell and then the Box itself)
Also renamed some of the Alternate Access Mappings (AAM)
Followed this guide: http://www.bluesphereinc.com/blog/renaming-a-sharepoint-20102013-server/

Central Administration back up and running and working

### The Problem

It looks like the Content Databases are still connected and on (from what I can tell from the Central Administration console) However my main SharePoint website doesn't seem to be working.

Can someone suggest some Fault finding procedures for me to find out where the fault is? Not sure if this is IIS or SP related right now.

### The wanted result

Once I've got the Websites confirmed working I will work on renaming the SQL Databases and disconnecting/reconnecting them (though not sure how to actually do this just yet) as I only have one SQL Box in my environment.

This should leave me nicely with;

- Live SP Server
- UAT SP Server
- SQL Server Hosting both sets of Databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my experience in past, it is very hard to copy the VMs and get a working SharePoint farm. SharePoint for some reason don't like it especially Config DB.

I would highly recomend that re create the Config DB( rebuilding the Farm) otherwise you will see alot unknown errors.

if your central admin is working, then do the following things.

- Central admin > APplication management > Databases: Specify the default database Server ...update the new SQL server over here.
- update the search topology if you are using it.
- Stop the un wanted services application.
- detach the content DB and re attach them.
- their are chances that you are conflicting with the URL, as you copy the DC from Production as well.

Always great if you share the error details/ screen shot.

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for the reply. It turns out that the issue was caused by a combination of the Unextend/Extend Web Application removing the majority of the site and customization and the fact that there was no Self signed SSL Cert when changing to a different host header.

Changing to http helped with the Cert and reverting the VM's back and starting again with the URL renaming (Changing IIS Bindings and SharePoint AAM Manually) worked.